# Join tables and select record using CriteriaQuery in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Parent` entity mapped to a `Child` entity through a `@OneToOne` mapping. Using `CriteriaQuery` how can I create a JOIN between these two entities and select records based on certain column matches? The code I am using right now is as follows

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Parent> query = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root<Parent> root = query.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent, Child> join = root.join("child_id", JoinType.INNER);
query.where
        (cb.and(cb.equal(join.get("child_id"), child_id)),
                (cb.equal(root.get("name"), name)));
TypedQuery<Parent> tQuery = createQuery(query);
return selectSingleOrNull(tQuery);
```

However, executing this code generates an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [child_id] on this ManagedType [com.example.test.db.entity.AbstractEntity]
```

The entities are structured as follows

```java
public class Parent extends AbstractEntity {
...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
    private Child child;
...
}
```

```java
public class Child extends AbstractEntity {
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long child_id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
    private Parent parent;
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class AbstractEntity {
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for AbstractEntity

Comment: @SridharPatnaik Sure. Updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

While joining tables, we should give name of the joining entity. In your case, you are using field if joining entity. Can you replace "child_id" with "child" in your join statement and try. So your code should be

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Parent> query = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root<Parent> root = query.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent, Child> join = root.join("child", JoinType.INNER);
query.where
        (cb.and(cb.equal(join.get("child_id"), child_id)),
                (cb.equal(root.get("name"), name)));
TypedQuery<Parent> tQuery = createQuery(query);
return selectSingleOrNull(tQuery);
```

Comment: From the documentation for the join method, the first input is the name of the attribute for the target of the join. I still tried changing it to the target entity name. Still shows the same error

Comment: I am sure it will be "child" and not child_id. But if its still not working, not sure. Everything else looks fine. Even I implemented similar example in my code. and it works fine. If this is just a demo application, can you share code over github?